# Ionic array does not filter when there is an input field

Tags: ionic-framework, search, filter

I am implementing a search filter function for my ionic app, together with firebase firestore but, the filter does not seem to work. I have been trying a lot of methods but it just does not seem to work. Would appreciate a lot if someone were to help me.. thank you..

**Typescript code here**

```
 recipeData: any = [];

 constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) { 
   this.initializeData();
 }

 initializeData() {
    // Getting recipe data from database
    this.recipeService.getAllRecipes().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.recipeData = data;
    });
  }

  filter(ev : any) {
    // Filtering code
   this.initializeData();

   const val = ev.target.value;
    if(val && val.trim() !== ''){
      this.recipeData = this.recipeData.filter((item) => {
        return(item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      });
    }
  }
```

**HTML code here**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor = "let item of recipeData">
    {{item.Name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `this.initializeData()` from filter method that's the issue.

Every time you call your filter method initializeData method got executed and in  initializeData method you are calling to rest api which take time to get data and before rest send the data to your subscribtion of `getAllRecipes()` code below `this.initializeData()` in filter method gets execute

```
const val = ev.target.value;
if(val && val.trim() !== '') {
  this.recipeData = this.recipeData.filter((item) => {
    return(item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
});
```

and then after subscribe code gets execute

```
getAllRecipes().subscribe((data) => {
  this.recipeData = data;
});
```

And that the reason you filtered recipeData is again gets the data which comes form rest api.

So the solution here is just `this.initializeData()` remove this from `filter(ev : any)` method.

updated filter(ev : any) method given below.

```
 filter(ev : any) {
    // Filtering code
   const val = ev.target.value;
    if(val && val.trim() !== ''){
      this.recipeData = this.recipeData.filter((item) => {
        return(item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: @thedeveloper123 please check the answer and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your help! I have already found the solution.. turns out I have to call the code for filtering into the subscribe function.. But nontheless, thank you so much! :-)

Comment: No worries. Please upvote and approve my answer if you think this is relevant answer. Thanks.